# Lightswitch (VB 2012) How to update part quantity field after sales order is placed?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am really a beginner in building Lightswitch applications. I am using VB programming language. I have a problem setting up quantity control... I managed to figure out validation and found one single working example of an update button and changed the code so it suits my needs. The code is:

```
 Private Sub DeductInventory_Execute()
        ' Write your code here.
        For Each orddetail As OrderDetail In Me.OrderDetails
            Dim currentproduct = Me.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Parts.Where(Function(o) o.Id = orddetail.Part.Id).FirstOrDefault()
            If currentproduct IsNot Nothing Then
                currentproduct.Quantity = (currentproduct.Quantity - orddetail.Quantity)
            Else
                Throw New Exception("Not enough quantity")
            End If
        Next
        Me.Save()
    End Sub
```

which works. But my problem is that i dont know how to auto trigger that button on order save. Tried putting the code in main save button but it doesnt work...

Best solution would be if i could put the code to " CreateNewSalesOrder_Saved() " event but when i put it there, it doesnt work...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. The code should go in *CreateNewSalesOrder*'s **Saving** method, not its **Saved** method.

If that doesn't solve the problem for you, you need to tell us more about "it doesn't work".